# I need help connecting Node.js Express to MariaDB via SSH using Sequelize."

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

model/index.js

```
let sequelize;
const sshClient = new Client();
sshClient.on('ready', () => {
console.log('SSH tunnel connected successfully.');
sequelize = new Sequelize(config.database, null, null, config);
const db = { sequelize, Sequelize, Op };
module.exports = db;});
sshClient.on('error', (error) => {console.error('SSH tunnel error:', error);});
sshClient.connect({
host: sshConfig.host,
port: sshConfig.port,
username: sshConfig.username,
privateKey: sshConfig.privateKey,});
```

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'query')

"I'm trying to connect Node.js Express with Sequelize to MariaDB via SSH."
If you're trying it for the first time, there's nothing wrong with it once you follow the format. I offer help.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.